# Show that $ 2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to show that $\mid 2^{\mathbb{N}} \mid \neq \mid \mathbb{N} \mid$. I wanted to proceed by the Absurd assuming that there is a bijection $\phi : \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow 2^{\mathbb{N}} $ but I can't find the absurdity.
The indication tells us to consider the set $\{ n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n \notin \phi(n) \}$ but I don't see how it is useful.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, there is no surjective map $f:X\rightarrow 2^{X}$, where $2^{X}$ is the set of subsets of $X$. Indeed, suppose that such $f$ exists and so is surjective. Then, there is some $x\in X$ which is mapped to $f(x)=\lbrace x\in X : x\notin f(x)\rbrace\in 2^{X}$. Now, note that $x\in f(x)$ means that $x\notin f(x)$ and that $x\notin f(x)$ means that $x\in f(x)$ which is absurd. In your case, $X=\mathbb{N}$.
Look for Cantor's diagonal argument.

Comment: $y=\lbrace x\in X : x\notin f(x)\rbrace$ is a subset of $X$ and thus an element of $2^{X}$. We assumed, towards a contradiction, that $f$ is surjective. This means there is some $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. The fact that $y$ is a subset is the same to say that $ZF$ defines it as such - so you can prove that $y$ is really a set contained in $x$, hence an element of $2^{X}$. Maybe I misunderstood your question!